# How to display text on the web page using python and HTML

Tags: python, text, html

I have very simple web page example read from html file using python. the html called led.html as in bellow:

```
<html>
<body>
<br>
<p>
<p>
<a href="?switch=1"><img src="images/on.png"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

and the python code is:

```
import cherrypy
import os.path
import struct
class Server(object):
    led_switch=1 
    def index(self,  switch=''):
        html = open('led.html','r').read()
        if switch:
            self.led_switch = int(switch)             
            print "Hellow world"            
        return html
    index.exposed = True

conf = {
        'global' : { 
            'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0', #0.0.0.0 or specific IP
            'server.socket_port': 8080 #server port
        },

        '/images': { #images served as static files
            'tools.staticdir.on': True,
            'tools.staticdir.dir': os.path.abspath('images')
        },

        '/favicon.ico': {  #favorite icon
            'tools.staticfile.on': True,  
            'tools.staticfile.filename': os.path.abspath("images/bulb.ico")
        }
    }
cherrypy.quickstart(Server(), config=conf)
```

The web page contain only one button called "on", when I click it I can see the text "Hello World " display on the terminal.
My question is how to make this text display on the web page over the "on" button after click on that button?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to use some kind of templating system.  I use [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/)  it's great!

Instead of...

```
html = open('led.html','r').read()
```

you would use...

```
import cherrypy
import os.path
import struct
from jinja2 import Template

class Server(object):
    led_switch=1 
    def index(self,  switch=''):
        myText = ''
        if switch:
            self.led_switch = int(switch)             
            myText = "Please Wait"
        html = Template("""
                <html>
                <body onload='setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("UserMessage").innerHTML = "Ok! it's done"}, 5000)'>
                <br>
                <p id="UserMessage">{{ htmlText }}<p>
                <a href="?switch=1"><img src="images/on.png"></a>
                </body>
                </html>
                """)

        return html.render(htmlText=myText)
    index.exposed = True

    conf = {
        'global' : { 
            'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0', #0.0.0.0 or specific IP
            'server.socket_port': 8080 #server port
        },

        '/images': { #images served as static files
            'tools.staticdir.on': True,
            'tools.staticdir.dir': os.path.abspath('images')
        },

        '/favicon.ico': {  #favorite icon
            'tools.staticfile.on': True,  
            'tools.staticfile.filename': os.path.abspath("images/bulb.ico")
        }
    }
cherrypy.quickstart(Server(), config=conf)
```

Hope this helps!

Andrew

Comment: Hi Andrew,
Thank you so much for the solution, its only need to change "import" to be "from" instead.Its good to combine them in one file since my original html is also not big.
I tried to modify the code so that it show me "Please wait ...." for about 5 seconds, then display "Ok! its done", but I couldn't.

        if switch:
            self.led_switch = int(switch)             
            myText = "Please wait ......"
            doing some tasks that take about 5 seconds
            myText = "Ok! its done"

Comment: Ok, I updated the code to show "Please Wait" then after 5 seconds it's changed to "Ok! it's done".  Is that what you're going for?

Comment: @majidhantoosh can you update your question to reflect the update code?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use Jinja (to avoid extra dependencies) you could still use string formatting:

```
class Server(object):
    led_switch=1 
    def index(self,  switch=''):
        myText = ''
        if switch:
            self.led_switch = int(switch)             
            myText = "Hellow world"
        html = """
         <html>
           <body>
             <br>
             <p>{htmlText}
             <p>
             <a href="?switch=1"><img src="images/on.png"></a>
           </body>
          </html>
                """
        return html.format(htmlText=myText)
```

Comment: Thanks btel for reply, what should I do in case of displaying "Please wait...." for some seconds after click the button and then display "Hello World" instead?? do you have idea?? Thanks

Comment: you could use `setTimeout` method in JavaScript. Alternatively, you could force reload the webpage.